# ' Syntax error help needed

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm new to Python and are having a problem with my game, The Quest for the Diamond Sword.
Whenever I run the script, it keeps coming up with

```
File "/Users/parent/Desktop/Python applets/The Quest for the Diamond Sword.py", line 16
    if direction == 'Right'
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried changing the ' to a ", but it won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a colon at the end; for example,

```
if direction == 'Right':
```